# Imagining an exponential "hypercomplex" system

Tags: abstract-algebra, hypercomplex-numbers, dual-numbers

I recently learned about hypercomplex systems that are taken over the reals, i.e. the dual numbers for which $j^2=1$, $j≠1$, and  the dual numbers for which $ε^2=0$, $ε≠0$. These number systems, along with the complex numbers, have some nice properties, namely they represent all the possibilities for 2-dimensional unital algebras over R, up to isomorphism.

They also happen to be constructed by polynomial equations, which begs the question: Is there a way to construct a "hypercomplex" system by defining the "imaginary constant" as a solution to an exponential equation? For example:

$a^k=b$, where $a,b∈\mathbb{R}$ and $k$ is the "imaginary unit".

The first thought I had was of somehow defining an algebra with the equation $e^{L}=0$, though I might just be being naive about the whole prospect in general.

Comment: If $e^L=0$, what would be $e^{-L}$?

Comment: What would $L^2$ be?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley if we talk about [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\overline {\mathbb R}$, where this equation has a solution, there $L=-\infty$ and $L^2=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

In [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\overline {\mathbb R}$, the solution for $e^L=0$ is $-\infty$.
Extending reals with logarithm of zro can be done in a [different](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432396/extending-reals-with-logarithm-of-zero-properties-and-reference-request) way as well.